# how to set up debit card payment method in magento

Tags: payment-methods

I don't want to set up using paypal debit. But as there is an option for credit card, I want to include "separate debit card payment method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user changes to the paypal website it is out of your scope and you can't do anything about this. So it is not in your powert to decide, whether the customer is then using a paypal account or a credit card.

But I think if you offer Paypal and Credit Card as two options in the checkout, most people who check out with credit card will choose credit card over paypal - problem solved, for most of them.

Comment: Sounds rude, but it isn't :-) Please don'T wrote thanks comments. If you want to say thank you vote up. If everyone who is grateful adds a comment, you won't find the question/answer anymore :-)

Comment: okay i will do the same....

Comment: Hello. But i have to add debit card payment method on my website.